# Making bootable USB drive

Tags: usb, flash, iso, drive, unetbootin

I have the Windows 7 iso and I wanted to make a bootable flash drive out of it. I used to use Unetbootin but they have now removed the option to show all drives. Can anyone suggest another program that can make a bootable flash drive?

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to write a Windows 7 .iso image to a USB flash drive from within Windows. How is this [related to Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)? (If it is related to Ubuntu, I recommend editing your question to explain how, and perhaps provide more details about what you're trying to do, if you think that would help.)

Comment: I think its related because this used to work on Ubuntu but now the program cannot recognize the flash drive.

Comment: You ran Unetbootin on Ubuntu? Or do you just mean that this technique worked for creating a booting flash drive of Ubuntu, but does not work for creating a bootable flash drive of Windows?

Comment: I meant that I ran Unetbootin before on Ubuntu and it works but now its not recognizing my flash drive in the program.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in step 2 of the [simple Ubuntu download and installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) (click **USB stick**, click **Windows**, then click **Show me how**), you can use the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to write .iso images (including Ubuntu .iso images) to USB flash drives.

Microsoft [maintains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/installing-win7-using-a-usb-stick) some Windows 7 specific instructions for creating a bootable Windows flash drive. If the above suggestion doesn't help, perhaps those will. (I cannot watch that video--I have Moonlight, but I'm still not able to watch that Silverlight video. But you're interested in doing this from Windows, and you can probably watch that video from Windows. As I commented, I do wonder if this is on-topic for AskUbuntu...)

Comment: But.. does this work to make a bootable USB out of a ***Windows*** iso?

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I just tried it but when I select the windows 7.iso, nothing apears in the top box.

Comment: @lieudusty I've added a section pointing to Microsoft's instructions for doing this with Windows 7. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Using gparted format the drive NTFS, set the boot flag.

Using Archive Manager extract the iso to the drive.

(or just copy the DVD to the drive).

That's it.